# setup virtualhost for zendframework on xampp using apache port 8080

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, virtualhost, vhosts

I'm beginner for zendframework.
Started learning from [Zend Tutorial](https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/getting-started/skeleton-application/).
Able to download zend skeleton application through composer.
As I'm using XAMPP (Port 8080), so I prefer to setup VirtualHost for skeleton application. But it didn't work.

My httpd-vhost.conf file contains (Enabled in httpd.conf)

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
DocumentRoot "E:\xampp\htdocs\app_zend\skeleton_application\public"
ServerName zf-tutorial.localhost
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
<Directory "E:\xampp\htdocs\app_zend\skeleton_application\public">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And my host file contains

```
127.0.0.1 zf-tutorial.localhost localhost
```

I get following screen when enter http://zf-tutorial.localhost:8080/

[Screenshot_object_not_found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKDMT.png)

Please help me to resolve this. Also I searched similar questions but not found any solution working for me.

Also I created vhost in similar way for my CodeIgniter project. And that works. But for zend its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `VirtualHost *:80`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "E:\xampp\htdocs\app_zend\skeleton_application\public"
  ServerName zf-tutorial.localhost
  SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
  <Directory "E:\xampp\htdocs\app_zend\skeleton_application\public">
      DirectoryIndex index.php
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for solution.
Yeah, it don't show me error message; but redirects me to xampp dashboard instead of zend skeleton application.
What am I doing wrong?
Please suggest

Comment: have you added .htaccess file inside your public directory, also update this "127.0.0.1 zf-tutorial.localhost"